# GA API v4 several DimensionFilter's works strange (php)

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I trying to get statistic by event using GA APi v4 on php.
Here is ga js on the page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       ga("send", "event", "eventCategory", "eventAction", "eventLabel");
    </script>
```

I want to get count of executions of this event(eventCategory), filtered by , eventAction and eventLabel. Here is my code, based on Google guide:

```
    function getReport($analytics) {

      $totalEvents = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
      $totalEvents->setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
      $totalEvents->setAlias("totalEvents");    

      $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
      $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:eventCategory');
      $dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
      $dimensionFilter->setExpressions('My_event name');                        

      $dimensionFilter2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
      $dimensionFilter2->setDimensionName('ga:eventAction');
      $dimensionFilter2->setOperator('EXACT');
      $dimensionFilter2->setExpressions('My_event_action'); 

      $dimensionFilter3 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
      $dimensionFilter3->setDimensionName('ga:eventLabel');
      $dimensionFilter3->setOperator('EXACT');
      $dimensionFilter3->setExpressions('My_event_label');  

      $dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause();
      $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2, $dimensionFilter3]);     

      $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
      $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
      $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
      $request->setMetrics(array($totalEvents));
      $request->setDimensionFilterClauses([$dimensionFilterClause]);
      $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
      $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
      return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    }
```

But i get strange results.

```
      $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter]);
```

As i understand, this is all executions of my event My_event_name. Answer from API, totalEvents: 1737

```
      $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2]);
```

In this case, i want to get all executions of My_event name, dut filtered by ga:eventAction = My_event_action. Answer from API, totalEvents: 1738
Count of filtered events greater then count of all events?

```
      $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2, $dimensionFilter3]);
```

In case of all filters answer is 1737 again.

In this settings i expect to receive number of execution of My_event name, filtered by ga:eventAction = My_event_action, and ga:eventLabel = My_event_label but something is going wrong. It seems that the filters do not work when their count is more than 1.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify how Google should treat the different filters: AND or OR? By default, it is OR. To switch it, add this line:
`$dimensionFilterClause->setOperator('AND');`